# How can I extract three columns but making research with only one column

Tags: text-processing

I'm trying to extract the information that corresponds with the number in the first column

```
1   M   0.9770  0.9564
2   S   0.9664  0.9441
3   D   0.9756  0.9336
4   N   0.9744  0.9243
```

I would like to grep only the row that has the "**4**" so the output look like this:

```
4   N   0.9744  0.9243
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `awk` excels at:

```
$ awk '$1==4' file
4   N   0.9744  0.9243
```

You can also use `grep`, if you want. Assuming your file is separated by spaces, you can search for lines that start with a `4` followed by a space:

```
$ grep '^4 ' file 
4   N   0.9744  0.9243
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the number in the first column (as you said it's just the line number) and instead just outputting line 4 using `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed -n 4p file
4   N   0.9744  0.9243
```

```bsh
$ sed '4!d' file
4   N   0.9744  0.9243
```

The same thing with `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk 'NR==4' file
4   N   0.9744  0.9243
```

Using `head` and `tail` to get line 4:

```bsh
$ head -n 4 file | tail -n 1
4   N   0.9744  0.9243
```